# onClick not working inside jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I'm having trouble figuring why the onClick event is not working inside jsFiddle. The code is working well on the browser, but when  try to port it to jsFiddle I lose the ability to fire the onClick events.

My current code is the following:

For the HTML:

```
<body>

<button id="find-near-btn" onClick="getMylocation()">
  Find companies near me
</button>  

<button id="mark-pos-btn" onClick="markMyPosition()">
  Mark my position
</button>  

<div id="mymap"></div>
<div id="output"></div>

</body>
```

The js:

```
function initmap(initialLat, initialLong){
  output.innerHTML += "<p>Initialized</p>";

  if(!initialLat || !initialLat.length){
        initialLat = 38.01693;
  }

  if(!initialLong || !initialLong.length){
    initialLong = -8.69475;
  }

  var mymap = this.mymap = L.map('mymap',{
    center: [initialLat, initialLong],
    zoom: 15
  });

  var osmUrl='http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
  var osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

  L.tileLayer(osmUrl, osmAttrib).addTo( mymap );
}

function getMylocation(){

  output.innerHTML += "<p>Obtaining location.</p>";

  if(navigator.geolocation){

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;

        mymap.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, long), 15);

    }, function (error) {
      // Get information based on IP
      getLatLongByIP();
    });
}
}

function getLatLongByIP()
{
  $.get("http://ip-api.com/json", function(response) {

    handleData(response.lat, response.lon);  
  }, "jsonp");
}

function handleData(lat, long){
  mymap.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, long), 15);
}

function markMyPosition()
{
    if(navigator.geolocation){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;

        L.marker([lat, long]).addTo(mymap);

    }, function (error) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          output.innerHTML += "<p>User denied the request for Geolocation.</p>";
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          output.innerHTML += "<p>Location information is unavailable.</p>";
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          output.innerHTML += "<p>The request to get user location timed out.</p>";
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          output.innerHTML += "<p>An unknown error occurred.</p>";
          break;
      }
    });
}
}

initialLat = 38.01693;
initialLong = -8.69475;

initmap(initialLat, initialLong);
```

The fiddle can be [found here](https://jsfiddle.net/DailyMatters/8vkuypLs/). When I click any of the buttons I get nothing. Any idea on how can I make this work?

Comment: In "Load type", choose `no wrap - in body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your JS code to be inside your page's `<body>` tag. Use the little cog at the top right of the Javascipt panel and choose `No wrap - in <body>` under `Load type`. [I already tested this and it works](https://jsfiddle.net/8vkuypLs/2/).